# Add ProtectedDate to Post records in the data dump

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, data-dump, protected-questions

The current version of the data dump does not have information on whether or not a question is protected.  Can we add a ProtectedDate column to this table?  It would be NULL on answer records and question records that are not yet protected.

Comment: +1 This is already in the schema, just not exposed in the data dump. I don't see a reason why it should be excluded.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why this still isn't present in the `Posts` table (besides perhaps lack of demand), but there is sufficient information in `PostHistory` now to determine if a post is currently protected if you really need it.

Grabbing the latest post history entry with a `PostHistoryTypeId` of 19 or 20 (protected and unprotected, respectively) will allow you to determine which questions were marked protected at the time the data was last updated, as you can see [in this example query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta/query/80377).